# Solution to Helmholtz equation with non-circular boundary

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Let $D$ be an homogeneous 2D domain with non-circular boundary $\partial D$.
I am trying to solve the Helmholtz equation 
$$
 \nabla^2 u(r, \varphi) + k^2  u(r, \varphi) = - f(r, \varphi)
$$

in which $k$ is constant.
The boundary condition is $u=0$ on the boundary.

The boundary $\partial D$ is deviated from a circle.

Objective: is there a set of basis functions (complete) such that any
$u$ in $D$ can be represented as
$$
  u(r, \varphi) = \Sigma_n c_n R_n(r)\Theta_n(\varphi)?
$$
Which functions are $R_n$ and $\Theta_n$? I want to numerically determine $c_n$ to make the approximate solution fit the Helmholtz equation and the
B.C. as well. If the boundary is circular, we know that $R_n$ is the
Bessel function; and $\Theta$ is just exponential.

Thanks in advance.